# Repartition of 1's in the "Chacon word"

Tags: nt.number-theory, ergodic-theory, symbolic-dynamics, combinatorics-on-words

Consider the "Chacon words": $B_0=0$ and $B_{n+1} = B_nB_n1B_n$. The word $B_n$ has $\ell_n := \frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}$ digits and the number of $1$'s in $B_n$ is $\ell_n - 3^n = \ell_{n-1}  \sim \ell_n/3$. There's also a word $B_\infty$ since $B_{n+1}$ is an extension of $B_n$.

While dealing with my own research, I discovered the following conjecture. Let $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ be $S = j\mathbb{Z} + k$ (density $d(S)=1/j$) or $S=\bigl\{n \mid \{n\gamma\} \in [a,b)\bigr\}$ (density $d(S)=b-a$, where $0 \leq a < b \leq 1$ and $\gamma \in (0,1)$ is irrational). Then:
$$
\frac{\#\{i \mid 1 \leq i \leq N, i \in S, B_\infty(i)=1 \}}{N} \underset{N \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} \frac{1}{3}d(S).
$$
Do you know a proof of this result ?

#### Update

Let me develop how I got this conjecture. According to Theorem 1 of [this paper by Hanson & Pledger](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00537020), the conjecture is equivalent to 
$$
(\ast)\colon \quad \frac{1}{\ell_n} \sum_{\substack{k=0 \\ B_n(k+1)=1}}^{\ell_n-1} f(T^k\cdot) \overset{L^2}{\longrightarrow} \frac{1}{3}E(f \mid {\cal I}) 
$$
for every invertible *mpt* $T$, every $f \in L^2$, and where ${\cal I}$ is the $T$-invariant $\sigma$-field.

In fact, I have almost proved $(\ast)$ (I have only proved it for ergodic $T$ - but this is pretty enough to get the necessity of the conjecture : the conjecture follows for $(\ast)$ applied to periodic transformations on $\mathbb{Z}/j\mathbb{Z}$ and to ergodic rotations).

Note that $(\ast)$ is very close to an application of the ergodic theorem. 
By the ergodic theorem applied to $T \times C$ where $C$ is the Chacon map and $T$ is ergodic (hence $T \times C$ is always ergodic), we have 
$$
(\#)\colon\quad \frac{1}{\ell_n} \sum_{k=0}^{\ell_n-1} f(T^kx){\boldsymbol 1}_{C^k u \in [2/3,1[} \longrightarrow \frac{1}{3}E(f) \quad \text{for almost all $(x,u)$},
$$
and for $u=0$ one has 
$$
\frac{1}{\ell_n} \sum_{k=0}^{\ell_n-1} f(T^kx){\boldsymbol 1}_{C^k u \in [2/3,1[} = 
\frac{1}{\ell_n} \sum_{\substack{k=0 \\ B_n(k+1)=1}}^{\ell_n-1} f(T^kx).
$$
But I don't know if something allows us to apply $(\#)$ for $u=0$. Anyway I wonder whether there is a proof of the conjecture without using $(\ast)$.

Comment: Perhaps I haven't understood the question properly: what happens if we take $S$ to be the set of all $i$ such that $B_\infty(i)=0$?

Comment: Do you mean something unusual by "natural density?" Are you only considering sets that are natural in the sense that they are not chosen to make this conjecture fail?

Comment: @DouglasZare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density

Comment: @IanMorris Thanks  for this remark. Indeed ! I need to do a correction.

Comment: If you mean the standard definition of natural density then your original conjecture is obviously false.

Comment: @DouglasZare I did a correction after Ian's comment. Do you still think it is wrong ?

Comment: The current version is much more reasonable than the original. Can there be any set that satisfies the original?

Comment: The natural thing to do is try to prove that the product of the Chacon system with an irrational rotation (or a periodic orbit) must be uniquely ergodic. However it is not clear to me how to do this.

Comment: @IanMorris. Is the Chacon map itself uniquely ergodic? If that is so then unique ergodicity of the cartesian square of the Chacon map with an irrational rotation will follow from Furstenberg's disjointedness paper since the Chacon map is weakly mixing and an irrational rotation is a Kroenecker (pure point spectrum) transformation.

Comment: @IanMorris How would you conclude with the unique ergodicity ? Does it imply that $(\#)$ hold for every $(x,u)$ ?

Comment: The Chacon map is uniquely ergodic and therefore by the comment before the product of the Chacon map with an irrational rotation is uniquely ergodic. This implies that for any Riemann integrable function $g$ on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ the Birkhoff averages  (w.r.t. $C\times T$ in your notation) converges at every point. Since the function you are considering is Riemann integrable then (#) holds for all $(x,u)$.